# Writing Python Dictionary with multiple keys to CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, export-to-csv, import-csv

How do I write a dictionary with multiple keys to csv vertically as shown in image? I can only use native packages such as csv.
[I am getting this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zmzu.png) but [I need this as an output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIged.png).

Below it the snippet (tried with different looping techniques) but didn't seem to work !

```
import csv

my_file = open("test.csv", mode="w")
sorted_keys = sorted(csv_dict)

writer = csv.DictWriter(my_file, fieldnames = sorted_keys, restval='')
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerow(csv_dict)
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Could you add the dictionary to the question? Not everyone would like to type it manually for you. Also, copy and paste the required output in the question than adding as an image file link.

Comment: Is Pandas an acceptable package?

Comment: no, only native packages are to be used so that the same script can be run on different machines.

Comment: @Pluviophile, my dictionary comes from a function whose parameters act as keys and values and the same function appends the key:values pair to dictionary.
Therefore I can not post the actual dictionary.

Comment: Can't you can print csv_dict to a terminal and copy/paste it?  Or edit it to make it shorter if required.

Comment: okay, take this for e.g
csv_dict = {
 'x' : [1,2],
 'y' : [4,6],
 'z' : [7,8],
 'm' : [9,10],
 'n'   : [1],
 'o' : [23],
 'p' : [12]
 }

Comment: if you could, please refer to this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66703451/python-dict-to-csv-with-last-value-written-instead-of-blanks

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, but this snippet worked

```
csv_file = 'file.csv'
with open(csv_file, 'wb') as fd:
writer = csv.writer(fd, delimiter=',')

keys = sorted(dictionary) 
# Format headers for aesthetics
headers = [' {} '.format(key) for key in keys]
writer.writerow(headers)

# Format data to create convenient csv format
csv_data = itertools.izip_longest(*(dictionary[key] for key in keys),
                                  fillvalue='     ')
writer.writerows(csv_data)
```